# .Xaml doesn't render unicode that write in the code?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, unicode, windows-store-apps

In .xaml of windows store app, If I write like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#x2606;" />
```

It will render a star.

But If I write like this in C# code:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock
{
    Text = "&#x2606;"
};
```

it won't render, why? How to render the unicode write in c# code??

Comment: maybe try `Text = "☆"` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&...;` notation is an XML encoding, there is no decoding applied to C# strings. Use

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock
{
    Text = "\x2606";
    // Or just:
    // Text = "☆";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using what is called an xmlunicode glyph... see [this list of unicode glyphs](https://github.com/ndw/xmlunicode/blob/master/unicode-glyph-list.el)

To output a stress outlined white star in c# you would specify the unicode as follows:

```
char c = '\u2729';
System.Console.WriteLine(c.ToString());
```

See [this link for a better description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

See [this link for a list of unicode characters and their respective codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)